# Order nodes by relationship count --> ThisShouldNotHappenError

Tags: neo4j, cypher

In a Neo4j database with a couple of nodes and relationships, I am trying to find out the most "popular" users (in this case: The nodes participating in most relationships):

```
START n=node:user('*:*')
MATCH (n)-[r]->(x)
RETURN n
ORDER BY COUNT(r) DESC
LIMIT 10
```

However, this query (Neo4j 1.9.2) results in the following error:

> ThisShouldNotHappenError
>
> Developer: Andres claims that: Aggregations should not be used like
>   this.
>
> StackTrace:
>   org.neo4j.cypher.internal.commands.expressions.AggregationExpression.apply(AggregationExpression.scala:31)
>   org.neo4j.cypher.internal.commands.expressions.AggregationExpression.apply(AggregationExpression.scala:29)
>   org.neo4j.cypher.internal.pipes.ExtractPipe$$anonfun$internalCreateResults$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(ExtractPipe.scala:47)
>   org.neo4j.cypher.internal.pipes.ExtractPipe$$anonfun$internalCreateResults$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(ExtractPipe.scala:45)
>   scala.collection.immutable.Map$Map1.foreach(Map.scala:109)
>   org.neo4j.cypher.internal.pipes.ExtractPipe$$anonfun$internalCreateResults$1.apply(ExtractPipe.scala:45)
>   org.neo4j.cypher.internal.pipes.ExtractPipe$$anonfun$internalCreateResults$1.apply(ExtractPipe.scala:44)
>   scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:328)
>   org.neo4j.cypher.internal.pipes.TopPipe.internalCreateResults(TopPipe.scala:45)
>   org.neo4j.cypher.internal.pipes.PipeWithSource.createResults(Pipe.scala:69)
>   org.neo4j.cypher.internal.pipes.PipeWithSource.createResults(Pipe.scala:66)
>   org.neo4j.cypher.internal.executionplan.ExecutionPlanImpl.org$neo4j$cypher$internal$executionplan$ExecutionPlanImpl$$prepareStateAndResult(ExecutionPlanImpl.scala:164)
>   org.neo4j.cypher.internal.executionplan.ExecutionPlanImpl$$anonfun$getLazyReadonlyQuery$1.apply(ExecutionPlanImpl.scala:139)
>   org.neo4j.cypher.internal.executionplan.ExecutionPlanImpl$$anonfun$getLazyReadonlyQuery$1.apply(ExecutionPlanImpl.scala:138)
>   org.neo4j.cypher.internal.executionplan.ExecutionPlanImpl.execute(ExecutionPlanImpl.scala:38)
>   org.neo4j.cypher.ExecutionEngine.execute(ExecutionEngine.scala:72)
>   org.neo4j.cypher.ExecutionEngine.execute(ExecutionEngine.scala:76)
>   org.neo4j.cypher.javacompat.ExecutionEngine.execute(ExecutionEngine.java:79)
>   org.neo4j.server.rest.web.CypherService.cypher(CypherService.java:94)
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:611)
>   org.neo4j.server.rest.security.SecurityFilter.doFilter(SecurityFilter.java:112)

Any ideas on how I can express this differntly?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

In terms of neo4j mannual, if you need to use an aggregration in your "Order by", you must include the aggregration in your "Return", so you just need to add the count(r) in your "Return" as shown below,

```
START n=node:user('*:*')
MATCH (n)-[r]->(x)
RETURN n, COUNT(r)
ORDER BY COUNT(r) DESC
LIMIT 10
```

Answer (score 5):

Introduce a `WITH` here:

```
START n=node:user('*:*')
MATCH (n)-[r]->()
WITH n, count(r) as c
RETURN n, c
ORDER BY c DESC
LIMIT 10
```

Comment: +1 You can actually just add it to the return: `return n, count(r) as c order by c`, `WITH` isn't necessary.